# Django using external mysql DB - best way to tackle

Tags: mysql, database, django, django-models

I have scanned all of the similar titles and questions regarding my issue and also the django website itself and I cannot find the best solution. I apologize if this has been answered.

My django is configured to use a MySQL database with information already inside of it.

I have a database with tables created inside of them in which I will only need to read from to build graphs.

Should I build a model for each one of these types of tables?

Basically a new table named simulation_log201403 is created each time we run a simulation. Inside of this we have a timestamp, node, ppsavg etc. This simulation ID is linked to a computer_id.

Do I have to hand create each model based off my old database?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  If you're asking how to use Django with a database not created by your Django models, read the chapter entitled [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it greatly!!
The link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/ - yours is dead!

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the link.